# How to leave a account of supergroup/channel with Telegram bot?

Tags: .net, .net-core, telegram, telegram-bot

I want to leave a accoun of channel/supergroup , I use this code.

```
  Client= new Td.TdClient();
  await Client.LeaveChatAsync(chatid);
```

when i use chatid of a group, it left the group.
but when i use chatid of supergroup/channel get error `Chat not found`.

i use chatid with -100, without -100 but get error

I use `.Net Core 3.1` , `TDLib 1.8.12` ,`TelegramBot 19.0.0`

Comment: you should use this method instead https://core.telegram.org/method/channels.leaveChannel AND please specify which framework or library are you using

Comment: Thanks, I use `.Net Core 3.1` , `TDLib 1.8.12` ,`TelegramBot 19.0.0`

Comment: can you confirm the chatId is actually valid? have you checked with  t.me/JsonDumpBot ?

Comment: yes, chat id is ok

Comment: this https://core.telegram.org/method/channels.leaveChannel method leave bot from channel, bot i want leave a account of channel

Comment: you want to `ban` a user ? use this method https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#banchatmember

Comment: I don have a bot for `ban`, I have a account (tdclient) and want to left the channel